# Kibana has blank page after upgrading to elasticsearch 1.4

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

After upgrading my elasticsearch to version 1.4 my kibana has stopped working. I've edited my elasticsearch config file to be good for Kibana (http.cors.enabled: true), so screen with message Can't connect to Elasticsearch has disappeared, but now I have only blank page.

[image: Kibana blank page]

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: kibana 3 has some issues with elasticsearch 1.4. You might want to take a look at your server and elasticsearch logs. It will very helpful if you post the error logs if there is any in your post

Comment: Unfortunately, when I'm trying to open Kibana, there is no extra log.

Comment: There is no logs in your apache server? or whatever server you are using?

Comment: In apache log there is one error after accessing Kibana and it is only about timezone settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found absolute url for creating new dashboard (`http://localhost/kibana3/#/dashboard/file/blank.json`), put it into browser, created and saved new dashboard and everything seems to be fine (maybe there were some saved dashboards from old version). Anyway, thanks for advices :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try Kibana 3 with ElasticSearch 1.3.x. There is some compatibility issue of Kibana with ES 1.4.0.